# How we can use the argment in rxjs/map operator

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

At rxjs,

```
export function map<T, R, A>(project: (this: A, value: T, index: number) => R, thisArg: A): OperatorFunction<T, R>;
```

I cannot find usage of `thisArg: A` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same purpose as in `Array.prototype.map` : context is lost when you pass a function as an argument.

```
class Value {
   constructor (public value:number) {}
   addValue (x:number) { return this.value + x; }
}

const five = new Value(5);
```

```
[1, 2, 3].map(five.addValue); // Error because this is undefined
```

```
[1, 2, 3].map(five.addValue, five); // [6, 7, 8]
```

---

RxJS example

```
const source = Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3]);

source.map(five.addValue); // NaN...NaN...NaN

source.map(five.addValue, five); // 6...7...8
```

Comment: i am asking about rxjs/map

Comment: Same answer. It's the same abstraction, it has the same problem with context in JS, and RxJS solves it the same way. I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Geoffrey, for the heads up, here is the rxjs version of it

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
class Value {
   constructor (value) {
    this.value = value;
   }
   addValue (x) { return this.value + x; }
}

const five = new Value(5);
// Example data
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
of(...numbers)
  .pipe(
    map(five.addValue, five) // This is the reference to the object having value 5
  )
  .subscribe(transformedData => {
    // Do something with the transformed data
    console.log(transformedData);
  });
```